# How to load Jqgrid Dropdown based on other dropdown data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jqgrid

I have two dropdown in my screen, One is a normal Razor dropdown and another one is Jqgrid dropdown. The Razor dropdown code is following,

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="" class="control-label">Loan Currency</label><br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LoanCurrency, Model.Currencies.ToSelectListItems(x => x.CurrencyCode, x => x.Id.ToString(), "", true, "", "Select"), new { @class = "form-control" }).DisableIf(() => Model.IsReadOnly == true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LoanCurrency)
</div>
```

And My Jqgrid

```
 jQuery("#grdDrawdownSchedule").jqGrid({
        url: RootUrl + 'ECB/DDSGridData',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        height: 130,
        colNames: ['id', 'Drawdown Date', 'Currency', 'Amount'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 30, sorttype: "int", editable: false, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'DdDate', index: 'DdDate', width: 130, align: 'left', editable: true,
                        editoptions: {
                            readonly: 'readonly',
                            size: 10, maxlengh: 10,
                            dataInit: function (element) {
                                $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy', changeMonth: true,
                                    changeYear: true, constrainInput: false, showOn: 'both',
                                    buttonImage: RootUrl + 'Content/Images/grid_Calendar.png',
                                    buttonText: 'Show Calendar',
                                    buttonImageOnly: true
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    { name: 'CurrencyName', index: 'CurrencyName', width: 120, editable: true, edittype: "select"      //, formatter: currencyFmatter
                    },
                    { name: 'Amount', index: 'Amount', align: "right", width: 120, editable: true,
                        editoptions: { size: "20", maxlength: "16", dataInit: function (element) {
                            $(element).keypress(function (e) {
                                $('#AvgMaturityLoan').val("0");
                                if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && e.which != 46 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
                                if (charCode == 46 && this.value.split('.').length > 1)
                                    return false;
                            });
                        }
                        }
                    },
        //{ name: 'tadte', index: 'tdate', width: 130, "editable": true, "sorttype": "date", editrules: { "date": true }, "editoptions": { "dataInit": "initDateEdit"} },                                               
                 ],
        loadComplete: function () {

            $("#grdDrawdownSchedule").setColProp('CurrencyName', { editoptions: { value: JSON.parse(Currencies)} });


        },
        cellEdit: true,
        rowNum: 100,
        rownumbers: true,
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        caption: "Drawdown Schedule",
        multiselect: true,
        shrinkToFit: false, forceFit: true,
        width: 490,
        postData: {
            "lrnid": "@Model.Id",
            "data": "@Model.drawdownSchedule"
        }

    });
```

And Addnew button for this grid

```
 $("#btnAddNewDrawdownSche").click(function () {

        if (ValidateRow($("#grdDrawdownSchedule"))) {
            var idAddRow = $("#grdDrawdownSchedule").getGridParam("reccount")
            emptyItem = [{ id: idAddRow + 1, DrawdownDate: "", Currency: "", amount: ""}];
            jQuery("#grdDrawdownSchedule").jqGrid('addRowData', 0, emptyItem);

        }
    });
```

When I click the Addnew button in my grid, then the Jqgrid dropdown should auto populate the razor dorpdown's data If it is not null. And the Jqgrid dropdown loaded from a variable named currencies such that is given below

```
var Currencies = $.ajax
                ({
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    url: RootUrl + "ECB/GetJsonCurrencies",
                    cache: true,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (!result) alert('No Currencies Found!!!');
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('Failure to retrieve Json.' + error.toString() + "~~~" + error.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }).responseText;

In which the GetJsonCurrencies method return a Json Currency list.
```

After choose the razor dropdown, user need to give details in grid, So when user click the addnew button in the grid, the Jqgrid Dropdown should auto populate the value which is choosed in the razor dropdown. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataInit` in `editoptions` like following. Perform your `ajax` call in `dataInit` function add populate your dropdown. Hope this will help you.

```
{
    name: 'CurrencyName',
    index: 'CurrencyName',
    width: 120,
    editable:true,
    edittype: 'select',
    editoptions: { dataInit : function (elem) { 
          var curr = $('#LoanCurrency').val(); //dropdown outside jqgrid value
          if(curr){
              //Your ajax call goes here and populate dropdown with 
              //by the data of ajax call like following.
              $(elem).empty();
              $(elem).append('<option>Currency name 1</option>');
              $(elem).append('<option>Currency name 2</option>');
              $(elem).append('<option>Currency name 3</option>');
          }
       } 
    } 
}
```

Js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/azim101/kzh8j6eh/